# Common Database Normalization Scenarios

Tags: database-normalization

I'm interested in reading a resource (book, or perhaps a web site) that covers normalization of database tables for common scenarios. I'm looking to store contact data for organizations, which includes addresses, phone numbers, as well as location data for places that may be any where in the world, and others.

I've read resources on database normalization theory, and have a decent understanding of 3NF, but I'm sure someone has already solved the problems I'm trying to solve, as they're extremely common. I'd like to review someone else's database design to see how (and maybe why) they chose to do it the way they did.

Any recommendations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest searching for 'Data Modeling Patterns'. A couple of books I found are
[Data Model Patterns: Conventions of Thought](http://www.librarything.com/work/294080) and [The Data Model Resource Book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0471353485). I have not read either, but the first seems to be the most revered discussing this topic, sort of the 'Martin Fowler of modeling. Another resource to keep in mind is [The Vietnam of Computer Science](http://blogs.tedneward.com/2006/06/26/The+Vietnam+Of+Computer+Science.aspx) - 'strict' normalization may not always be the best for your particular application.